# Link with hover need double click

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone

I have a problem with an apple on my site.
All buttons that have a "hover" event in CSS require to double click on it.
The first click triggers the "hover" and the second triggers the redirection

I would like to know if it was possible not to trigger the "hover" but to redirect to the link at the first click.

I found this piece of code but makes the click very sensitive if the scroll while pressing a link,  link is triggered

```
var device = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var ios = device.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/)
if (ios) {
   $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
       var el = $(this);
       var link = el.attr('href');
       window.location = link;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it can be solve in CSS...
That's an UX Problem
Check that : https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/